# What is sum of squares when it comes to variance (calculation in Java)?

Tags: java

Summary: Program asks user to enter their number of shoes (0-200). Once they type in a non-number, calculations are made.

Variables made are:

```
 int numberOfShoes =0;int highNumber = 0;
 int lowNumber = 0;
 int sumofShoesInputted = 0;
 int sumOfSquares = 0;
 double mean = 0;
 double variance = 0;
 double standardDeviation = 0;
```

The formula for variance for a part of my program is:
    `variance = (sumofTheSquares - (sumOfShoesInputted*sumOfShoesInputted /     numberOfShoes)) / numberOfShoes -1)`

for standard deviation it's
`Math.sqrt(variance);`

I'm just confused what exactly is the "sum of the squares" part.

*Would also like to add that the formula was given to me.

**Even though it's homework I'm completely confused by this ONE thing. I'm not asking you to write my program. Just asking for a simple explanation.

Comment: `SumOfTheSquares = Sum of square of each of the value`

Comment: What is the so called square though, what you said was vague.

Comment: square is the second power. square(a)=a^2=a*a.

Comment: Some people are so proud that they know what the square is, that they immediately punish the one who doesn't know that, because of not being English or old enough. Pfuj! +1 to the question, Hold on, boy! Or girl.

Comment: More like I didn't understand the meaning of "sum of squares," I know what square is (a*a). I fully understand it now, just have to translate it in code.

Answer (score 1):

The sum of the squares of a set of numbers `A1, A2, ... ,AN`
is the expression `A1*A1 + A2*A2 + ... + AN*AN`. This is what
is meant here.

Comment: So it's basically multiplying each value by itself?

Comment: Yes, and then summing them up.

Comment: The x^2 = x*x is called square of x in Mathematics. That's because if you have a square (geometry) with side x, its area is x*x.

Comment: So sum of the squares is taking the sum of the data inputted and multiplying it by itself? That's odd, I thought I did that though (sumOfShoesInputted*sumOfShoesInputted).

**ex: data inputted would be
10
20
30

then the sum of the squares does 10*10 + 20*20 + 30 *30?**

Comment: Thank you so much, took me a while but now I understand it. If I had 15 reputation I would click the useful button.